# MEAN stack templates with grunt-angular-templates

Tags: javascript, angularjs, templates, mean

I'd like to reduce the load time in my MEAN project.
So I would like to "minify" my Angular views, with the help of [grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates).

It generates successfully a "templates.js", with all my templates :

```
angular.module('core').run(['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
    // My templates here
}]);
```

So I want all my views loaded in one time with this file.
I'm using "$stateProvider" to configure my routes.

The problem is that I don't know where to put my templates, and how to tell $stateProvider the templates instead of the views.

Thank you

Comment: if keys used to store in `$templateCache` are same as templateURL angular will already find them in $templateCache before attempting to do ajax. A simple way to include them would be to have them as a separate module and add that module to main module dependencies array

Comment: @charlietfl For example I tried to put this in my "templates.js" file :

    $templateCache.put('/modules/core/views/home.client.view.html', "<h3>Html goes here</h3>");

My route is defined like that :

      $stateProvider.state('home', {
   url: '/',
   templateUrl: '/modules/core/views/home.client.view.html'
  });

But the original "home.client.view.html" view is still here on '/'.

Maybe the order of my .js files inclusions has an impact on this.

Thank you

Comment: Sorry for the indent :

https://gist.github.com/VJJB/ea609161793928c7bf22

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can take a deep look on this  explanation https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates
Here's an example of the output created by this task from multiple .html files:

```
angular.module('app').run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("home.html",
    // contents for home.html ...
  );
  ...
  $templateCache.put("src/app/templates/button.html",
    // contents for button.html
  );
}]);
```

Then, when you use ng-include or templateUrl with $routeProvider, the template is already loaded without an extra AJAX request!

for your query "where to put template" you can see these examples
Examples
Register HTML Templates in app Module

```
ngtemplates:  {
  app:        {
    src:      '**.html',
    dest:     'templates.js'
  }
}
```

Register Relative Template URLs

Normally, your app, templates, & server are in separate folders, which means that the template URL is different from the file path.

```
ngtemplates:  {
  app:        {
    cwd:      'src/app',
    src:      'templates/**.html',
    dest:     'build/app.templates.js'
  }
}
```

This will store the template URL as templates/home.html instead of src/app/templates/home.html, which would cause a 404.
Minify Template HTML

Simply pass the same options as the htmlmin task:

```
ngtemplates:    {
  app:          {
    src:        '**.html',
    dest:       'templates.js',
    options:    {
      htmlmin:  { collapseWhitespace: true, collapseBooleanAttributes: true }
    }
  }
}
```

Or, if you already have an existing htmlmin task, you can reference it:

```
ngtemplates:    {
  app:          {
    src:        '**.html',
    dest:       'templates.js',
    options:    {
      htmlmin:  '<%= htmlmin.app %>'
    }
  }
}
```

Customize Template URL

Suppose you only use ngtemplates when on production, but locally you serve templates via Node, sans the .html extension.

You can specify a url callback to further customize the registered URL:

```
ngtemplates:  {
  app:        {
    src:      '**.html',
    dest:     'templates.js',
    options:  {
      url:    function(url) { return url.replace('.html', ''); }
    }
  }
}
```

Customize Output

Some people like AMD & RequireJS and would like wrap the output in AMD or something else (don't ask me why!):

```
   ngtemplates:      {
      app:            {
        src:          '**.html',
        dest:         'templates.js',
        options:      {
          bootstrap:  function(module, script) {
            return 'define(' + module + ', [], function() { return { init: ' + script + ' }; });';
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You will be able to custom everything surrounding $templateCache.put(...).

Comment: Thank you for this perfect answer.